# exception with Linq to SQL using sdf file

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, sql-server-ce

I've set up a project with an SDF local database file and am trying to access it using an LINQ To SQL (".dbml") file. I have used the connection string provided by the sdf file and can instanciate the object with out a problem:

```
thisDataContext = new MyDataContext(GetConnectionString());
```

However, whenever i try to access any information from it eg

```
var collection = (from MyObject p in thisDataContext.MyTable select p);
```

I get the error -

"The table name is not valid. [ Token line number (if known) = 2,Token line offset (if known) = 14,Table name = Person ]"

I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 .Net 3.5 and SQL 2008 CE.

I gather something similar happened for SQL 2005 CE and a Hotfix was released, but i would have thought the fix would have been fixed in this version before release.

Does anyone know the fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get rid of the "dbo" in the Table attributes on the objects created by Linq to Sql

e.g.:

```
[Table(Name="dbo.Orders")]
class Order
{

}
```

Change that to:

```
[Table(Name="Orders")]
class Order
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks @BFree, that has worked like a charm. I've been hunting for a fix for a while.